# Android Cannot detect file in internal storage with Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I have Android Studio with an emulator

I copied the file `mobilenetv2-10.onnx` to `/sdcard/Download` int he emulator by dragging it on top of the window

I can check the file exists on device with `View->Tool Windows->Device File Explorer`

However, when I run the following code in Java it does not enter the `if` statement

```
    File f = new File("/sdcard/Download/mobilenetv2-10.onnx");
    if(f.exists()) {
        boolean t = f.exists();
    }
```

Why is this file not detected?

I tried removing `/` before `sdcard` but it still does not work

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On Android 11+, your app does not have read access to files in `Downloads/`, unless your app was the one to put the file there.

Please consider using the Storage Access Framework (`ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`/`ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument`). The user can choose to open that file, or open something else, at the user's discretion.